# Whitechapel murder location

Tags: whitechapel

I've been playing a lot of whitchapel with friends lately and we were wondering about a certain rule:

It states that a prostitute may not be placed on the same location as a previous murder.
What would happen if a prostitute moved to another location and was murdered there? In the next night can a prostitute start on the same location the last prostitute started, seeing as the murder didn't happen on that location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about [Letters from Whitechapel](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/products/letters-from-whitechapel/).

## Wretched Pawns may never occupy the same space as a Crime Scene marker, whether as a result of Jack the Ripper's Woman token placement or the movement of the Head of the Investigation.

Rule citations are as follows:

- In Phase two of the First Part of a night (page 9 in the rulebook), when Jack the Ripper is placing the Woman tokens, he cannot place any on a red circle that also has a red Crime Scene marker (a location that he had killed a target on any previous night). This restriction applies even if it is an unmarked (decoy) Woman token being placed.
- In Phase six of the First Part of a night (page 13), there are Four restrictions on the movement of Wretched Pawns:

  1. The movement must end on an unoccupied numbered circle.
  2. The movement must not cross over a Police Patrol token.
  3. The movement must not end adjacent to a Police Patrol token.
  4. The movement must not end with the Wretched Pawn on a circle with a red Crime Scene marker.

In short, if a Wretched Pawn would end up on the same numbered circle as a crime scene marker, the movement (or Woman token placement) is illegal.

---

## Jack is permitted to reuse the same numbered red circle for multiple nights

There is no rule forbidding Jack from placing a marked Woman token on, say, 65 (a Red numbered circle), waiting once (so that the resulting Wretched pawn moves off the red numbered circle), murdering that pawn, and then placing another Woman token (marked or not) on 65 the next night.

Interestingly enough, forbidding this reuse of red numbered circles (or Jack not waiting during the first two nights, thus placing crime scene markers on two red numbered circles) actually makes it very easy to perform an "instant arrest" on Night 3, as Jack's mandatory first move is to move to one of the two murders that night, thereby giving the inspectors the first move of that night. If the inspectors have cops positioned in a way that they can reach and perform an arrest on both murder sites on that first move, Jack loses, and the likelihood of this goes up significantly if two of the numbered red circles have crime scene markers on them (preventing Jack from placing Woman tokens on them).

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, i was specifically asking what would happen if a woman moved from a red circle to another numbered circle and was murdered there, can another woman start on that same red circle the next round seeing as a murder didn't occur there

Comment: Except it does. The ONLY restriction on Woman token placement that Jack has is that he can't place a Woman token on a red numbered circle that has a Crime Scene marker. So long as there is no crime scene marker on the red numbered circle itself, Jack can continue to keep placing Woman tokens on it on successive nights, they may still be marked, and Wretched pawns spawned this way can still be murdered. It may not be in Jack's best interest to do so for consecutive days, but strategy wasn't asked about, only whether it was legal to do so.

Comment: if you'll add this to your answer I will accept it, you're right I didn't ask about strategy because i'm not concerned if it is a strategically good move

Comment: edited. On a related note, there's some interesting strategies that come up if Jack is in fact forbidden from re-using red numbered circles, such as the Instant Arrest strategy on night 3 (which horribly skews the game in the investigators' favor). Again, strategy is actually out of scope, but the existence of such a strategy actually justifies the ability to reuse red numbered circles... provided Jack didn't murder a pawn on the red circle itself.

Comment: instant arrest on night 3 happened in the last game I supervised, the detectives were smart and placed investigators next to a murder location but jack wasn't smart and started next to an investigator instead one of the murder locations were there wasn't an investigator, which was pretty dumb imo